# Functions are not valid as a React child when lazy loading

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app where I am lazy loading a component after authorization has been completed on an Auth0 protected route.

To be clear, it seems to load `ParticipantComponent` just fine and displays its internals. So this isn't critical but I do want to avoid any unforeseen consequences of this error.

The error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it. 
    Suspense  
    Suspense 
    index.js:1
    e index.js:1
    overrideMethod react_devtools_backend.js:2560
    React 13
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 4
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 3
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:417
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:390
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:157
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    js scheduler.development.js:180
    js scheduler.development.js:645
    Webpack 21
```

The only thing that makes this error disappear is if I do not lazy load any component at all. I have tried moving Suspense up and down the tree, as well as lazy loading `ParticipantDash` instead of `ParticipantComponent`. The error will only disappear when I have absolutely no lazy loading anywhere in the app. I have also attempted to just use Route in place of `ProtectedRoute` and the issue persists.

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Suspense fallback={Loading}>
    <Router basename="/app">
      <Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
        <App /> 
      </Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
    </Router>
  </Suspense>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

App.js:

```
import ParticipantDash from "./views/participantdash";

export default function App() {

  const {isLoading, isAuthenticated, logout} = useAuth0();
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isAuthenticated){
      history.push("/login");
    } else {
      history.push("/home");
    }
  });

  if(isLoading){
    return <Loading/>
  } else {  
    return(
      <Fragment>
          <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={ParticipantDash}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Splash}/>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

protected-routes.js:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component, ...args }) => {
    return(
        <Route
            component={withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
            onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
            })}
            {...args}
        />
    )
};
```

participantdash.js:

```
const ParticipantComponent = React.lazy(() => import("../components/participantcomponent"));

const ParticipantDash = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ParticipantComponent/>
        </Fragment>
    )
};
```

participantcomponent.js:

```
const ParticipantComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div> ParticipantComponent </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `<Suspense fallback={Loading}>` should be `<Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>`. Let me know if it fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `Loading` is a react component. `fallback` props of `Suspense` component must be a component.

You need to pass `<Loading/>` as fallback instead of just `Loading`.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
    <Router basename="/app">
      <Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
        <App /> 
      </Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
    </Router>
  </Suspense>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Damn really? That seems like an anti-pattern. Anyway that fixed it thanks